# Rename subdirectory files of other subdirectories recursively on powershell?

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm a total newb to scripting and shell in general but I'd like to automate this because is going to take me a long time. 
I have a folder with 37 folders in it, and in these 37 folders, there are a varied number of subdirectories, 10, 12, etc. And in these subdirectories there are images that go to 0 to the n-number of images in the subdirectory.

So my Folder is like this:

`G(Main Folder) > G1, G2...G37`

And, for example, in G1:
`G1 > G'1,G'2,G'3...`

And this for every G-n folder in G.

I'd like to rename all the images in the G'n folders according to the Gn folder where it currently is. For example: in G1, there are 8 folders (G'1,G'2, etc.), in the first one, there are 10 images, so I'd like to rename them all from 00 to 10, then in the second one, there are 18 images, so starting from 11, i'd like to rename them from 11 to 18, and so on. And then move all those images to the G1 folder.

All of this also applied to the rest of the 37 G folders and their 300-and-something subdirectories.
Thanks!

Comment: is there actually a single quote in the directory names? [*frown*]

Comment: you can renumber/rename the files in sequence by loading ALL of them, sorting by the full path, and then renaming the files in that sequence. [*grin*]

Comment: Give it a go, then when you get stuck post your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'v created some testfolders and files and this worked for me. Please make sure you create a testfolder/backup when running this script.

```
$folderInMainFolder = ls "D:\G"

$n = 0
$i = 0

foreach($folder in $folderInMainFolder){

    $items = ls $folder.FullName

    foreach($item in $items)
    {
        Rename-Item $item.FullName -NewName "$n$i.jpg" -Force
        $i++

        if($i -eq 10)
        {
            $i = 0
            $n++
        }
    }
}

#Move all the files to the directory G1
Get-ChildItem "D:\G" -Filter *.jpg -Exclude "D:\G\G1" -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination "D:\G\G1" -Force
```